# htaccess Redirect BEFORE RewriteRule?

Tags: .htaccess

This is my htaccess:

```
## Rewrites
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    Redirect /stream/ http://twitch.tv/8wayrun
    Redirect /stream http://twitch.tv/8wayrun

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?8wayrun\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://8wayrun.com/calibur/$1 [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Basically, I need to to rewrite 8wayrun.com/stream to twitch.tv/8wayrun...

And then I need it to rewrite 8wayrun.com to 8wayrun.com/calibur...

The problem is, its rewriting 8wayrun.com/stream to 8wayrun.com/calibur/stream. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try placing the flag L, after first two redirects.

Comment: You mean like `Redirect /stream/ http://twitch.tv/8wayrun [L]
    Redirect /stream http://twitch.tv/8wayrun [L]`? Tried it, gives me server errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Redirect` directive is part of mod_alias, and the `Rewrite*` directives are part of mod_rewrite. When a URI gets processed through the URL/file mapping pipeline, both modules get applied so having one in front of the other doesn't matter, both will get applied in the end.

You're better off sticking with only mod_rewrite and using the `L` flag to prevent the extra redirects from geting applied.

```
## Rewrites
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^/?stream/? http://twitch.tv/8wayrun [R=302,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?8wayrun\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://8wayrun.com/calibur/$1 [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: re "both will get applied in the end"; Order guaranteed?